# RandomAccessFile: Getting Java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I have the code:

```
junk.writeUTF("Jim");
junk.writeInt(9304029);
junk.writeUTF("England");

junk.writeUTF("Bob");
junk.writeInt(99291933);
junk.writeUTF("Canada");

junk.seek(12);
String name = junk.readUTF();
int number = junk.readInt();
String city = junk.readUTF();
```

When I run it I am getting the error message saying it's null.  I get why this is happening but how do I know which byte to seek to so I can read the data for Bob?  seek(12) is giving null.

Comment: Do you have to use `writeUTF()`? Knowing the length of the written data in UTF form is pretty hard. Versus `writeBytes()` or `writeChars()`, where the byte offset is just the length of the string (or length of string * 2).

Comment: EOFException isn't 'null'. Make up your mind. You need to read the documentation for writeUTF(). It writes more bytes than you are accounting for, but in any case I have no idea where you got the 12 from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` isn't 2 bytes, it's 4. And [`writeUTF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) writes a 2-byte length prefix, so the total length is supposed to be 18.

If we consider the offsets of each piece of data:

```
            Offset
UTF length  0
Jim         2
9304029     5
UTF length  9
England     11
```

When you pass in 12, it will try to read a UTF string using `ng` as the length, which is 28263, which is obviously a bit longer than your file.